# How to convert a function into a WebApi function in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC project which has MVC App and WebApi in it. T

The WebApi is used by the MVC App to do the business logic and return objects. I had never tried to access to the Web Api with Chrom or somethingelse. But now, we have decided WebApi to be accessible by all our customer via HTTP protocol, I mean it should be accesible with Chrome like a regular WebApi projects.

What should I do to make the WebApi public to all? Should I add a TAG above of the function?

here are important parts of my ApiController which should be public

```
public class CustomerApiController : ApiController
{

[LocalizationWebApi]
[SessionControlWebApi]
[ScreenAccess(SCREEN_ACCESS.Show)]
public JsonResult<CustomerOrderFormSearchResult> CustomerOrderFormSearch(CustomerOrderFormSearchModel Model_)
{

    CustomerOrderFormSearchResult ret_ = new CustomerOrderFormSearchResult();
    ret_.Errors.Add(ResourceExtensions.Language("SHARED_MESSAGE_SESSIONCLOSED"));
        return Json(ret_, IgnoreEntityProxyContractResolver.Create());
}

}
```

Comment: If I get your question correctly, You want to access you web api using browser? If yes just configure the route properly In your case it might be configured properly run the project and access the route. you will get your response

Comment: yes, but do I need to add [HttpPost]

Comment: Yes You need to add. But in your case you need to add [HttpGet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think you need to add the action verb with you controller action method example `[HttpPost],[HttpGet],[HttpPut]` etc. in your case you need to use `[HttpGet]` because it is plane get call. Modify your controller like

```
public class CustomerApiController : ApiController
{
[LocalizationWebApi]
[HttpGet]
[SessionControlWebApi]
[ScreenAccess(SCREEN_ACCESS.Show)]
public JsonResult<CustomerOrderFormSearchResult> CustomerOrderFormSearch(CustomerOrderFormSearchModel Model_)
{
       CustomerOrderFormSearchResult ret_ = new CustomerOrderFormSearchResult();
       ret_.Errors.Add(ResourceExtensions.Language("SHARED_MESSAGE_SESSIONCLOSED"));
       return OK(ret_);
       //Better to return Ok in your search result
      // If you want validation use NotFound() or something slimier to that 
 }
}
```

Always be careful about the route configuration of your api.